# WCF remote debugging fails - no symbols loaded

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, iis

I am trying to remotely debug wcf service on IIS 6. It has been working fine until yesterday. Now breakpoints are not being hit and warning message says "No symbols have been loaded for this document". I've solved this by restarting iis and app pool, but it worked just for a few days. Now I have the same problem. I've read almost all advices on the Internet about this, I've checked build options, GAC, ASP Temporary folder. When the service file is loading the VS  is writing that my dlls is loaded. But when I looking at the debug->modules window it shows that this modules haven't been loaded. I still can see exceptions while debugging. Now I am temporarily using Debug.WriteLn() for debugging, but it takes a lot of time and effort. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I  use VS 2010, WinXp Sp3 on my PC and Windows Server 2003 on server.

[Updated] Is there any patches for VS 2010 that can fix remote debugging problem ?

[Updated] I've noticed that w3wp process type is x86 now, although my service was called by client before and it should be managed type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I 've found a solution. I copy my WCF output files to the same location on the server as in my pc. It is quite wierd but debugging works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, and the issue I ran into:

> I've noticed that w3wp process type is x86 now, although my service
>   was called by client before and it should be managed type.

Typically to get the w3wp.exe process to actually show in the **Attach to Process** debug dialog is to just browse to a site in IIS locally. This will spin up that process and make sure it is available to select.

*However*, you must browse to a site using the *same* app pool type as the WCF service you want to debug. If you select an app pool using a 32-bit process (x86) and attach to this for a WCF service expecting a x64 version, the resulting *"No symbols have been loaded for this document"* will be displayed and breakpoints will appear as 'hollow' red circles.

Answer (score 0):

First: Please Install IIS 7, its much recommended!

2nd: it happens sometimes with everyone I guess, deploying the service again with the options (Delete existing files (checked), with source code (checked) ), resolves the problem.

Actually that's the only solution is working in my case

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: I always delete existing files as well as cleaning ASP Temporary folder. WCF servece is deployed with source code and in debug mode. Unfortunately I can't install IIS 7, but debugging has been worked fine for months until that problem occured.

Comment: Try associate a new and different application-domain with your WCF service, (should be totally dedicated to your wcf service, and no other application).

Comment: I've created a new domain and now debugging is working. Is there any explanation of this bug ?

Comment: check the other applications, which are using the old application domain, may be they are being a reason to stop debugging for others. Or check your application domain configuration. Well, there are many reason. My best practice in development is setup separate application domain for each service / application. So in case if anyone causes to crash to worker process, other doesn't get hurt.

Comment: I have only one application for each domain. And it doesn't work again. I tried to debug my app this morning and I got the same problem. Although I've created a few new domains to solve this problem, it doesn't help.